principal ideal domain and semi simple ring
Here is a exercise from hungerford.
A principal ideal domain $R$  is semisimple if and only if $R$  is a field or $R$ contains an infinite number of distinct nonassociate irreducible elements.
Def:
A ring is called semisimple if its Jacobson radical is zero.
Here is my approach:
($\Rightarrow$)I separate it into semisimple and simple and not simple case. If it is simple, then $R$ is also primitive, so $R$ is a field. Next for the not simple case, I don't know what is relation between irreducible elements and non simple ring.
($\Leftarrow$) if $R$ is a field, it is clear that $R$ is semisimple, again, I don't konw how to use the condition, "$R$ contains an infinite number of distinct nonassociate irreducible elements."
Can someone help me. Thanks in advance.

For $\Rightarrow$, suppose $R$ contains only a finite number of such irreducible elements which are respectively $p_1,...,p_r$, then $p_1...p_r \in \text{Jac}(R)$, which is a contradiction;
For the other direction, assume that $\text{Jac(R)} \neq 0$, then for $x \in \text{Jac(R)}$, $p_i | x$ for every irreducible element. We may pick some irreducible element $p_i$ and let $x_i = x \cdot(p_1^{-1}...p_i^{-1})$, then we have an ascending chain of ideals:
$$(x) \subseteq (x_1) \subseteq ...\subseteq (x_n) \subseteq ...$$
However, PIDs are Noetherian, thus there is some $(x_N) = (x_{k}), k>N$ and $N>>0$, but this means that there is only finitely many irreducible components of $R$, as desired.

What is $p_i^{-1}$

@lee If $p_i|x$ then $x = p_i y$. Since $R$ is a PID, there is some $p_i^{-1}$, inverse of $p_i$ in the quotient field and one can see that $y = p_i^{-1}x$
